# Using chunked upload/StartUpload with sharepoint REST api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, chunked

I want to upload large files to sahrepoint online but I am unable to use chunked upload of sharepoint REST api. I would like to see a working example.

the api is described in here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileStartUpload
using the methods

startUpload(GUID, stream1) 
continueUpload(GUID, 10 MB, stream2)
continueUpload(GUID, 20 MB, stream3)
finishUpload(GUID, 30 MB, stream4)

I found the same question in 
**https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5596f87a-3155-4e4f-a6e8-8d38fa5e580d/office-365-onedrive-for-businesssharepoint-rest-api-startupload-command?forum=appsforsharepoint**

but the solution uses C# and I need REST.