# How can I use FinishUpload to close a chunked file upload when I have 0 bytes left?

Tags: rest, file-upload, sharepoint-online, chunks

I'm uploading files, in chunks, to SharePoint Online through the REST API.
I am doing this via the `StartUpload`, `ContinueUpload` and `FinishUpload` methods and passing them a chunk as a `byte[]`.

I have used this as the example to work from: [Using chunked upload/StartUpload with sharepoint REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605892/using-chunked-upload-startupload-with-sharepoint-rest-api)

Documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.startupload.aspx

(I have not included the code as I don't think it's relevant, please correct me if I'm mistaken)

This works as long as the total file size is larger than the chunk size.
For example, if the chunk size is 1MB, but the total file size is 4MB, then the method will work.
If the chunk size is 4MB, but the total file size is 1MB, then I end up with empty or corrupt files once uploaded.

This is because the initial call to `StartUpload` contains the entire file in one chunk, so `FinishUpload` never gets called to close the file.

If I call `FinishUpload` with an empty `byte[0]` then I get:

> Error 500 - Internal Server Error: The upload was incomplete. Try to save again.

Under normal circumstances I would simply check if the total file size was smaller than the chunk size and instead add the file directly using `/Files/add(...)`.

Unfortunately I am being passed the file chunks in a stream and I don't know the total file size beforehand. I also can't save all chunks before processing, I have to pass each chunk straight to SharePoint as I am given them.

**So how do I use FinishUpload to close a file upload when I have no more bytes to upload?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that matter you could consider the following modifications:

1) in case if *total file size is less then chunk size*, then the file
   is getting uploaded via a single request. For example:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
if(fi.Length <= chunkSize)
{
   this.UploadFile(address, fileName);
   return;
}
```

where [`WebClient.UploadFile` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for uploading a file via SharePoint RPC

2) otherwise file is getting uploaded via chunk session

Refer [SharePointClient.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/41872624b010f3f5c730#file-sharepointclient-cs) for a complete example.

Comment: While you're not technically wrong, you're also not right. I don't know the file size beforehand so don't know whether I can upload in a single request. I'm not using the SharePoint SDK libraries, I'm using the REST API so can't use SharePoint Client.

Comment: @Equalsk, if you take a look at the example i provided, you will notice there is **no** any dependency SharePoint SDK libraries, only REST (chunk upload) & RPC (single upload) APIs are utilized

Comment: Oh, my bad. I saw the name of the class and made the wrong assumption. I think this is as close to an answer as I'll get, but I'm going to wait just a little longer before accepting. I actually solved the problem a different way by filling up a buffer until it was full or I had no bytes left to fill it with. Then I was able to tell which way to upload.

Comment: But of course instead of RPC you could utilize REST API to [upload a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)

Comment: I'm using `HttpClient` to interact with the REST API and at the moment it seems to be working well. Thanks for your help so far.